# Как в JQuery реализовать scroll по нажатию

Tags: jquery, прокрутка, click

Как реализовать скролл к верху/низу списка по нажатию кнопок up/down соответственно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нажимаю на кнопку и только один раз прокручивается

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#up").click(function(event) {
    $("#list").scrollTop(100);
  });

  $("#down").click(function(event) {
    $("#list").scrollTop(-100);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("#up").click(function(event) {
    $("#list").scrollTop($("#list").scrollTop()+100);
});

$("#down").click(function(event) {
    $("#list").scrollTop($("#list").scrollTop()-100);
});

});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое..

Comment: @Roman поставь галочку пожалуйста)